# How to append query to the column values with other id value

Tags: sql, oracle

```
    table format:
    id,path,reformated_path
    123,"https://www.ddf.com/wewe/rer/ff/w.jpg","https://www.ddf.com/wewe/rer/ff/123_w.jpg"
    124,"https://www.ddf.com/wewe/rer/ff/eewe/2324.00.jpg","https://www.ddf.com/wewe/rer/ff/eewe/124_2324.00.jpg"
125,"https://www.ddf.com/wewe/rer/ff/eewe/23.00.png","https://www.ddf.com/wewe/rer/ff/eewe/125_23.00.png"
```

desired result : is `reformated_path` column value

Here I am trying to append `id` column value into ending section(or file name) of `path` as `reformated_path` column.
I tried using `regexp_substr(path,'[^/]+',6,6)` but it applied to few column only

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the combination of `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` as follows:

```
SQL> WITH YOUR_TABLE(ID, PATH) AS
  2  (SELECT 123,'https://www.ddf.com/wewe/rer/ff/w.jpg' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 124, 'https://www.ddf.com/wewe/rer/ff/eewe/2324.00.jpg' FROM DUAL)
  4  -- Your query starts from here
  5  SELECT ID, PATH,
  6     SUBSTR(PATH, 1,
  7    INSTR(PATH,'/',-1))
  8    || ID || '_'
  9    || SUBSTR(PATH,
 10       INSTR(PATH,'/',-1)+1) FORMATTED_PATH
 11    FROM YOUR_TABLE;

        ID PATH                                               FORMATTED_PATH
---------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------
       123 https://www.ddf.com/wewe/rer/ff/w.jpg              https://www.ddf.com/wewe/rer/ff/123_w.jpg
       124 https://www.ddf.com/wewe/rer/ff/eewe/2324.00.jpg   https://www.ddf.com/wewe/rer/ff/eewe/124_2324.00.jpg

SQL>
```